# How to get variables value outside $http.get?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

New to angularjs. I have a simple controller which reads a json file using `$http.get`. Inside `get` I am assigning some values to variable `$scope.testTotal`. But they revert to default value when exiting `$http.get`. It is confusing that when I log the entire object to console, I can see the values but when logging a specific value it shows zero.  Could it be a variable scope issue or execution sequence issue?

```
'use strict';
var app = angular.module("myApp", [ 'ngRoute']);

app.controller("SummaryController", ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.testTotal = {
        executionStatus: { total: 0, passed: 0, failed: 0, duration: 0 }
    };

    $http.get('dummy.json').success(function (data) {
        $scope.data = data;
        angular.forEach($scope.data, function (i) {
            $scope.testTotal.executionStatus.passed += i.passed;
            $scope.testTotal.executionStatus.failed += i.failed;
        });
    });

    console.log($scope.testTotal); //I can see nested object with assigned values
    console.log($scope.testTotal.executionStatus.passed); //Vanished. Shows default value zero
}]);
```

dummy.json has

```
[
    {"passed": 30, "failed": 12},
    {"passed": 10, "failed": 8}
]
```

### edit

I have created http://plnkr.co/edit/GlrrB0DkoAXCGpVsC2La. The objective of my question is: read value(s) from a nested json file (synchronously or asynchronously), assign it to a variable/object and use it to make a chart. Unfortunately I am unable to access the values I read.

Comment: I highly doubt that the first line is outputting `{"executionStatus": { "total": 0, "passed": 40, "failed": 20, "duration": 0}}` and then the very next line is outputting `0` for `$scope.testTotal.executionStatus.passed`.  You stated in comments on another answer that you attempted to simplify the code here; there must be something that is occurring between the first statement and the second that you are not showing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An $http.get call is asynchronous. At the moment the last two console.log() lines are executing, you have sent an AJAX request, but the response has not been received yet.

When it's received, the callback function passed to `success()` will be executed. Only then, you can know the new values and access the data:

```
$http.get('dummy.json').success(function (data) {
    $scope.data = data;
    angular.forEach($scope.data, function (i) {
        $scope.testTotal.executionStatus.passed = 90;
        $scope.testTotal.executionStatus.failed = 25;
        $scope.testTotal.executionStatus.total = 115;
    });
    console.log($scope.testTotal); 
    console.log($scope.testTotal.executionStatus.passed);
});
```

Note that the forEach loop doesn't make much sense: you're assigning, in a loop, a constant value to each of the `$scope.testTotal.executionStatus` attributes. Why use a loop if it does the same thing at each iteration?

Comment: It makes sense, but the confusing part is how the first console.log statement is able to show assigned values? By the way, the loop do not make sense here but I have trimmed down the code to show the core part of the problem.

Comment: It displays assigned values because the first thing your controller does, before sending the GET request, is to assign hard-coded values.

Comment: I have edited my json and code to read values from json to check if that assumption is true but it isn't.

Comment: That's very unclear. You should tell which code you're now executing, and what you see in the console. A plunkr would be nice as well.

Answer (score 0):

`$scope.testTotal.executionStatus.passed` is a value, it's logged immediately. Since `$http.get` is asynchronous it's the original value.

`$scope.testTotal` is an object containing other objects. To see the value of `passed` you have to open the object tree. It's not before that moment when `passed` is printed and at that moment it already has been assigned the new value.